# Area under the curve in risk prediction model

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, prediction, validation, auc

The area under the curve for my data set is $0.63$.

However, when I divided my data randomly into two parts, development (67%) and validation (33%), the value of the area under the curve became $0.58$ which is lower than on all data.

The value for the validation data set gave me similar to the development data set.

Any idea or suggestion why when I divided my data set, the area under the curve became lower than the whole data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assessing the performance on all data conflates the out-of-sample performance estimate on the test set, with the in-sample performance on the train set. You shouldn't assess the performance of your model on all data, only on the test set.

In addition, a different random split may give widely different results. You may therefore want to look into cross-validation, or optimism bootstrap instead.

Lastly, if the difference in train and test performance is large (i.e. the test AUC is much lower than the train AUC), your model is likely overfitting.